# Export Graph in BMP format in SAS

Tags: sas, bmp, sas-ods

Currently I'm trying to export a SAS graph to a .bmp image format. I achieved  a .bmp file but it is unreadeable.

```
    ods HTML body="C:\Users\example.bmp";

    proc gchart DATA=WORK.TABLE;
    VBAR CENTRE/ SUMVAR=CONTRACTS SUBGROUP="TRAM";
    run;
    quit;

    ods HTML close;
```

Does anyone knows how to correctly export a graph to a .bmp format?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use the extension HTML, the graph gets created and the HTML file links to the graph. You may need to set the goption device to BMP as well. If you have the option the SG graphical procedures make it easier to control the output.

Comment: Do you have to use gchart or are you happy to use the new SAS graphics template language?

Comment: Thanks Reeza and Robert Penridge. Finally I solved it using            ods_all_close; ods listing;  filename grafout 'path/Graphic.bmp' ; goptions reset=all gsfname=grafout gsfmode=replace device=bmp;  (GRAPH SENTENCE)   filename grafout clear;